# Example of semigroup of mappings

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

**Want some examples of semigroup of mappings.**

Let $X$ be a Banach space and consider the collection of mappings $\tau =\{T_t:t\ge 0\}$. Define, $T_t:X \to X$ by
$$T_t(x)=xe^t \text{  for all }x\in X.$$
Then for $s,t\ge 0$ we have $T_{s+t}(x)=xe^{s+t}=(xe^t)e^s=(T_tx)e^s=T_s(T_tx)$. Hence the collection $\tau$ forms a semigroup of mappings.

I want some examples of another new type of semigroup of mappings.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What kind of space is $X$? For example if $X = \mathbb{R}^d$ or $= \mathbb{C}^d$ then $T_t x = \exp\left(tA\right)x$ is a semi-group where $A$ is a matrix or for a Banach space space we could define a semi-group similarly with a bounded operator. Also $T_t = ae^t$ is not a semi-group: $T_s T_t x = T_s xae^t = xa^2 e^{s + t} \neq x a e^{s + t} = T_{s+t} x$.

Comment: $X$ is Banach space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few simple examples for such one-parameter semigroups of operators on a Banach space $X$:

1. Operator exponential functions: Let $A: X \to X$ be a bounded linear operator and set $T_t := e^{tA} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^kA^k}{k!}$ for each $t \ge 0$ (or even each $t \in \mathbb{R}$).
   As a special case, one obtains matrix semigroups when $X$ is finite-dimensional.
2. Shift semigroup: Let $X = L^p(\mathbb{R})$ and $(T_tf)(\omega) = f(\omega-t)$ for  $f \in X$ and $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$.
3. Nilpotent shift semigroup: Let $X = L^p([0,1])$, and set
   $$
     (T_tf)(\omega) =
     \begin{cases}
       f(\omega-t) \quad & \text{if } \omega \ge t, \\ 
       0 \quad & \text{if } \omega < t.
     \end{cases}
   $$
   for $f \in X$ and $\omega \in [0,1]$.
4. Periodic shift semigroup: Let $X = L^p(\mathbb{T})$, where $\mathbb{T}$ denotes the complex unit circle, and set $(T_tf)(\omega) = f(e^{it}\omega)$ for $f \in X$ and $\omega \in \mathbb{T}$.
5. Heat semigroup (also called Gausian semigroup): Let $X = L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and set $T_tf = k_t \star f$ for $f \in X$, where $\star$ denotes convolution over $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $k_t$ denotes the [heat kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel) on $\mathbb{R}^d$.
   This semigroup describes the solutions of the heat equation on $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
6. Convolution with the [probability mass function of the Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Probability_mass_function): Let $X = \ell^1(\mathbb{N}_0)$ and set $T_t x = k_t \star x$ for each $x \in  X$, where $\star$ now denotes the convolution over $\mathbb{N_0}$, and $k_t(k) := e^{-t} \frac{t^k}{k!}$ denotes the density of the Poisson distribution with expected value $t$.

There are many more examples, and things become interesting when the semigroups can't be written down explicitly anymore, but their so-called *generators* can. This is the main idea of *$C_0$-semigroup theory*, which is at the heart of infinite dimensional linear evolution equations. An excellent reference for this topic is the [book by Engel and Nagel](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0952.47036) (available online for free on the hompage of Rainer Nagel: [link](https://www.math.uni-tuebingen.de/de/forschung/agfa/members/engel-nagel_one-parameter-semigroups.pdf)).

Comment: For the example 2., $T_{s+t}(f)=f(s+t-w)$. and $T_s(T_t(f))=T_s(f(t-w))=f(s-t+w)$. How it forms a semigroup ? Can you please explain a little bit for this?

Comment: @Empty: Ah sorry, sign error. Fixed. (Same for 3.)